# Creating LI dynamically in Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$.each(data.TrendingProducts, function (i, item) {
    $("#trendcontent").append('<li>')
        .append('<div class="product-wrapper">')
        .append('<div class="image-wrapper">');
    $("<img/>").attr("src", item.Image).appendTo("#trendcontent");
    $("#trendcontent").append('</div>').append('</div').append('</li>');
});


<ul class="large-block-grid-3 small-block-grid-3">
    <div id="trendcontent"></div>           
</ul>
```

Hi I am trying to create an unordered list in jquery however the lists are not formed properly. Any suggestions/help?

Comment: One suggestion would be to indent your code properly. That often helps in spotting problems with logic and program flow.

Comment: I agree Asad. But I guess I am missing something here basically, the li tag gets generated and closes immediately.

Comment: You can't add a partial element to the dom.

Comment: Append the whole thing in one go. Define a new element

var k = $("<li><div class=\"product-wrapper\"><div class=\"image-wrapper\"></div></div></li>")

then just insert the image into the interior wrapper div. Appending malformed dom elements will cause odd things to happen

Comment: @JTravakh I second that. It's faster too.

Comment: @AlexAdams Could you please show what your expected markup is? Right now you should be getting a list item for each element in `TrendingProducts`, which contains a `div.product-wrapper`, which in turn contains a `div.image-wrapper`. The `li`s will alternate with images that you're inserting directly into `#trendcontent`.

Comment: This was asked five minutes ago! You can't insert a "half" element into the DOM.

Comment: ^ Beat me by a couple seconds. `;)`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. You do not need to append closing tags; jQuery handles DOM representations of elements, not markup.
2. `#trendcontent` is a `<div>`, and you're not supposed to add `<li>` elements to a `<div>` (use an unordered list `<ul>` or ordered list `<ol>`)
3. Even if `#trendcontent` were a list, you're inserting `<img />` elements directly into it, alternating with `<li>` elements. This is invalid HTML. Where your images should go depends on your requirements, but they're certainly not supposed to be siblings of `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should chain the children off of each append, you can't append half an element, so try something like this

```
  $('#trendcontent').append(
    $('<li>').append(
        $('<div>').attr('class','product-wrapper').append(
            $('<div>').attr('class', 'image-wrapper').append(
                $("<img>").attr("src", item.Image)
            )
        )
     )
  );
```

As stated else where, make sure #trendcontent is a UL, and not a DIV too.